# Spring mongodb: Aggregation unable to specify graphLookup.maxDepth

Tags: java, spring, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I recently updated to the latest spring mongodb 1.10 to try out the new `$graphLookup` aggregator. However, I can't seem to specify all the parameters for the `graphLookup`.

Specifically I can set `startWith`, `connectFrom`, and `connectTo` successfully, but `as`, and `maxDepth` don't seem to be visible.

**This works:**

```
Aggregation.graphLookup("relationships")
        .startWith("destination")
        .connectFrom("destination")
        .connectTo("source")
    ;
```

**This does not:**

```
Aggregation.graphLookup("relationships")
        .startWith("destination")
        .connectFrom("destination")
        .connectTo("source")
        .maxDepth("2")
        .as("relationshipGraph")
    ;
```

Looking at the spring source code it seems the class returned by `connectTo` `GraphLookupOperationBuilder` is static and final.

Is there another way to set `maxDepth`, or is this a bug?

Comment: That's a bug. I created https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still a release candidate version but looks like it is a bug. You can use the below workaround using `AggregationOperation` which lets you create a aggregation pipeline.

```
 AggregationOperation aggregation = new AggregationOperation() {
            @Override
            public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
                DBObject graphLookup = new BasicDBObject(
                                "from", "relationships"). append(
                                "startWith", "$destination").append(
                                "connectFromField", "destination").append(
                                "connectToField", "source").append(
                                "maxDepth", 2).append(
                                "as", "relationshipGraph");
                return new BasicDBObject("$graphLookup", graphLookup);
            }
        };
```

Comment: I thought 1.10 was an official release. Either way thanks I will use this workaround in the meantime.